# jquery can't get the change event on select element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i have this code the jquery code never got triggered 
none of the scripts are triggered :

```
 $('select[name=privileges]').change(function(){
      alert("id");
            var id = $(this).find(':selected')[0].id;
            alert(id);
        $('#changevalue').val(id);
      })
```

or this:

```
   $("#privileges_select").change(function() {
        alert($('#privileges_select option:selected').html());
     });

  <form method="GET" action="create_new_user.php">          
         user:<input  type="text" size="40"   name="user_name"/> 
         password:<input  type="text" size="40"   name="password"/>       
          <select name=privileges  id="privileges_select">
          <option name='opt_1'>admin</option>
              <option name='opt_2'>ordinary</option>            
             </select>
         <input type="hidden" name="item_options_id" value="" id="changevalue" />

          <input type="submit" value ="create" />
          <input type="reset" />

       </form>
```

in the end i like to send the selected option id in the form get

Comment: This works: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/ggnWy/ You need to be sure you're waiting for the page to load or the DOM is ready; what you've shown does not depict that being handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you add the script references for jquery?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

.....

</script>
```

Comment: Yes, its a bit old, got it from an old page, it should support the change() function, but your right, use the latest version  1.8.23

Answer (score 0):

try putting the name attr in quotes `<select name="privileges" id="privileges_select">`

and maybe terminating the `.change()` line with a semicolon;

basically it seems to work fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/N6bua/

Comment: Note, that's adding the handler within a `window.onload`. This is what I think the the OP has missed.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which the code matters. The change event listener has to be installed after the page contains the select element, otherwise it silently fails.

Try wrapping the handler with `$(function() { ... install handler here ... });`